# Dynamically received <xref> tags, how to make use of them?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags, wordnik

So I've been messing around with the Wordnik API, getting definitions from it and displaying them in a `<h2>` tag in the browser. This has all not been a problem, and my (honestly, crude) code can be found below.
Now, I just used "trees" to get their definition. What came out was "Plural form of `<xref>tree</xref>` with the `<xref>` tags inside the string.

This is obviously intended, but I've been wondering how exactly to actually get that `<xref>` tag to render properly, as a hyperlink to do a fetch request with the word "tree". Like in Wikipedia, basically.

Since responses can sometimes consist of multiple different `<xref>` tags, just finding one tag and using it wouldn't be enough, most of the time.

Any suggestions on this? I hope I formulated my question correctly. I've usually just lurked on stackoverflow, never actually asked questions.

My current code, which works, is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classes from "./SearchInputForm.module.css";

const SearchInputForm = (props) => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState("");

  const searchSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
    console.log(inputText);
  };

  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/${inputText}/definitions?limit=5&includeRelated=false&useCanonical=true&includeTags=false&api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_WORDNIK_API_KEY}`
    );
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonData);
    setFetchedData(jsonData[0].text)
  }

  const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputText(event.target.value);
    console.log(inputText);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <form onSubmit={searchSubmitHandler}>
      <input
        type="string"
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        placeholder="Enter words here!"
        value={inputText}
      ></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Search!"></input>
    </form>
    <h2>{fetchedData}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchInputForm;
```

I tried finding out how exactly to use tags inside strings as components or elements in ReactJS, but I haven't found out anything, unfortunately. The API's documentation also is not helping.